# Python: string of arguments to arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python I have a string that looks like this:

```
str = '1,2,3,4'
```

I have a method that takes four arguments:

```
def i_take_four_arguments(a, b, c, d):
  return a + b + c + d
```

What do I have to do to string to allow it to be sent to the method?

Comment: str.split(‘,’) On a different note, don’t use str As your variable  names. It’s an inbuilt function

Comment: Try: `i_take_four_arguments(*str.split(','))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to perform arithmetic operation, following is one way. The idea is to convert your split string values to integers and then pass them to the function. The `*` here unpacks the `generator` into 4 values which are taken by `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` respectively.

A word of caution: Don't use [in-built](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) function names as variables. In your case, it means don't use `str`

```
string = '1,2,3,4'


def i_take_four_arguments(a, b, c, d):
    return a + b + c + d

i_take_four_arguments(*map(int, string.split(',')))
# 10
```

Comment: This more than does the trick, thanks so much!

Comment: @cd-rum : You’re more than welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
str = '1,2,3,4'
list_ints = [int(x) for x in str.split(',')]
```

This will give you a list of integers, which can be added, pass them to your function

Comment: This is only the first part of the answer. A list would constitute only a single argument to the function, you'd need `*` to expand the list to 4 separate arguments.

Comment: Yeah, I just assumed that the OP wanted to convert the string to numbers, so that they can be passed to a function that does addition. My bad!